# ipsec site to site vpn sometimes not work

Tags: linux, networking, centos, vpn, ipsec

I have a problem with ipsec(strongswan) site to site vpn on CentOS (Linux).

I have 2 tunnel in my network

```
Security Associations (2 up, 0 connecting):
gateway-second[2]: ESTABLISHED 6 minutes ago, XX.XX.XX.XXX[10.10.20.1]...YY.YY.YYY.YY[YY.YY.YYY.YY]
gateway-second{2}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 2, ESP SPIs: c016f8d5_i 0e88a657_o
gateway-second{2}:   10.10.20.1/32 === 10.5.30.144/32
gateway-first[1]: ESTABLISHED 6 minutes ago, XX.XX.XX.XXX[10.10.21.1]...YY.YY.YYY.YY[YY.YY.YYY.YY]
gateway-first{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP SPIs: cd51497c_i 118e08a0_o
gateway-first{1}:   10.10.21.1/32 === 10.5.31.26/32
```

So my question is, sometimes when i restart vpn server traffic going to tunnel, but sometimes not.. it very strange and i not know what search about it. Maybe you know ?

This is my ipsec.conf

```
conn myikesettings
  keyexchange=ikev2
  authby=secret
  left=%defaultroute
  right=XX.XX.XXX.XX
  type=tunnel
  ike=aes256-sha256-modp1024!
  esp=aes256-sha1!
  keyingtries=3
  ikelifetime=86400s
  lifetime=36000
  pfs=no
  closeaction=hold
conn gateway-first
  leftid=10.10.21.1
  leftsubnet=10.10.21.1/32
  rightsubnet=10.5.31.26/32
  also=myikesettings
  auto=start
conn gateway-second
  leftid=10.10.20.1
  leftsubnet=10.10.20.1/32
  rightsubnet=10.5.30.144/32
  also=myikesettings
  auto=start
```

--- charon.log ---

```
Apr  7 20:30:14 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/strongswan/ipsec.secrets'
Apr  7 20:30:14 00[CFG] loaded IKE secret for XX.XX.XX.XXX YY.YY.YYY.YY
Apr  7 20:30:14 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon aes des rc2 sha2 sha1 md4 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints acert pubkey pkcs1 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl gcrypt fips-prf gmp curve25519 xcbc cmac hmac ctr ccm gcm curl attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default farp stroke vici updown eap-identity eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-mschapv2 eap-tls eap-ttls eap-peap xauth-generic xauth-eap xauth-pam xauth-noauth dhcp unity
Apr  7 20:30:14 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Apr  7 20:30:14 06[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'gateway-second'
Apr  7 20:30:14 06[CFG] added configuration 'gateway-second'
Apr  7 20:30:14 07[CFG] received stroke: initiate 'gateway-second'
Apr  7 20:30:14 07[IKE] <gateway-second|1> initiating IKE_SA gateway-second[1] to YY.YY.YYY.YY
Apr  7 20:30:14 07[ENC] <gateway-second|1> generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
Apr  7 20:30:14 07[NET] <gateway-second|1> sending packet: from XX.XX.XX.XXX[500] to YY.YY.YYY.YY[500] (338 bytes)
Apr  7 20:30:14 09[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'gateway-first'
Apr  7 20:30:14 09[CFG] added configuration 'gateway-first'
Apr  7 20:30:14 11[CFG] received stroke: initiate 'gateway-first'
Apr  7 20:30:14 11[IKE] <gateway-first|2> initiating IKE_SA gateway-first[2] to YY.YY.YYY.YY
Apr  7 20:30:14 11[ENC] <gateway-first|2> generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
Apr  7 20:30:14 11[NET] <gateway-first|2> sending packet: from XX.XX.XX.XXX[500] to YY.YY.YYY.YY[500] (338 bytes)
Apr  7 20:30:14 13[NET] <gateway-second|1> received packet: from YY.YY.YYY.YY[500] to XX.XX.XX.XXX[500] (438 bytes)
Apr  7 20:30:14 13[ENC] <gateway-second|1> parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No V V N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) V ]
Apr  7 20:30:14 13[IKE] <gateway-second|1> received Cisco Delete Reason vendor ID
Apr  7 20:30:14 13[IKE] <gateway-second|1> received Cisco Copyright (c) 2009 vendor ID
Apr  7 20:30:14 13[IKE] <gateway-second|1> received FRAGMENTATION vendor ID
Apr  7 20:30:14 13[IKE] <gateway-second|1> authentication of '10.10.21.1' (myself) with pre-shared key
Apr  7 20:30:14 13[IKE] <gateway-second|1> establishing CHILD_SA gateway-second
Apr  7 20:30:14 13[ENC] <gateway-second|1> generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) IDr AUTH SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(ADD_4_ADDR) N(ADD_4_ADDR) N(EAP_ONLY) N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) ]
Apr  7 20:30:14 13[NET] <gateway-second|1> sending packet: from XX.XX.XX.XXX[4500] to YY.YY.YYY.YY[4500] (288 bytes)
Apr  7 20:30:14 15[NET] <gateway-first|2> received packet: from YY.YY.YYY.YY[500] to XX.XX.XX.XXX[500] (438 bytes)
Apr  7 20:30:14 15[ENC] <gateway-first|2> parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No V V N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) V ]
Apr  7 20:30:14 15[IKE] <gateway-first|2> received Cisco Delete Reason vendor ID
Apr  7 20:30:14 15[IKE] <gateway-first|2> received Cisco Copyright (c) 2009 vendor ID
Apr  7 20:30:14 15[IKE] <gateway-first|2> received FRAGMENTATION vendor ID
Apr  7 20:30:14 15[IKE] <gateway-first|2> authentication of '10.10.20.1' (myself) with pre-shared key
Apr  7 20:30:14 15[IKE] <gateway-first|2> establishing CHILD_SA gateway-first
Apr  7 20:30:14 15[ENC] <gateway-first|2> generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) IDr AUTH SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(ADD_4_ADDR) N(ADD_4_ADDR) N(EAP_ONLY) N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) ]
Apr  7 20:30:14 15[NET] <gateway-first|2> sending packet: from XX.XX.XX.XXX[4500] to YY.YY.YYY.YY[4500] (288 bytes)
Apr  7 20:30:14 05[NET] <gateway-second|1> received packet: from YY.YY.YYY.YY[4500] to XX.XX.XX.XXX[4500] (256 bytes)
Apr  7 20:30:14 05[ENC] <gateway-second|1> parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ V IDr AUTH SA TSi TSr N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) N(NON_FIRST_FRAG) ]
Apr  7 20:30:14 05[IKE] <gateway-second|1> authentication of 'YY.YY.YYY.YY' with pre-shared key successful
Apr  7 20:30:14 05[IKE] <gateway-second|1> IKE_SA gateway-second[1] established between XX.XX.XX.XXX[10.10.21.1]...YY.YY.YYY.YY[YY.YY.YYY.YY]
Apr  7 20:30:14 05[IKE] <gateway-second|1> scheduling reauthentication in 85478s
Apr  7 20:30:14 05[IKE] <gateway-second|1> maximum IKE_SA lifetime 86018s
Apr  7 20:30:14 05[IKE] <gateway-second|1> received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
Apr  7 20:30:14 05[IKE] <gateway-second|1> CHILD_SA gateway-second{1} established with SPIs c341bc05_i d8e034cf_o and TS 10.10.21.1/32 === 10.5.31.26/32
Apr  7 20:30:14 04[NET] <gateway-first|2> received packet: from YY.YY.YYY.YY[4500] to XX.XX.XX.XXX[4500] (256 bytes)
Apr  7 20:30:14 04[ENC] <gateway-first|2> parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ V IDr AUTH SA TSi TSr N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) N(NON_FIRST_FRAG) ]
Apr  7 20:30:14 04[IKE] <gateway-first|2> authentication of 'YY.YY.YYY.YY' with pre-shared key successful
Apr  7 20:30:14 04[IKE] <gateway-first|2> IKE_SA gateway-first[2] established between XX.XX.XX.XXX[10.10.20.1]...YY.YY.YYY.YY[YY.YY.YYY.YY]
Apr  7 20:30:14 04[IKE] <gateway-first|2> scheduling reauthentication in 85371s
Apr  7 20:30:14 04[IKE] <gateway-first|2> maximum IKE_SA lifetime 85911s
Apr  7 20:30:14 04[IKE] <gateway-first|2> received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
Apr  7 20:30:14 04[IKE] <gateway-first|2> CHILD_SA gateway-first{2} established with SPIs cc5c14b6_i d89a3328_o and TS 10.10.20.1/32 === 10.5.30.144/32
```

Comment: look at charon's logs (if there are none, configure charon to actually do logs), and see what happens when you attempt the connection. Perhaps for example a wrong source IP is chosen and no match is found.

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes i look at charon's log but not find anything what will help to undestrand problem, ip is corrent if ip does'not corrent he dont connet anytime yes ?
buy traffic sometimes go to tunnel, but sometimes not..

Comment: i add charon log to question. thnx..

Comment: You'll have to give an example of non-working traffic vs working traffic for somebody to be able to help. Perhaps state what special condition appears to be related to it (special software...). Also obfuscating every IP with XX.XX. ... doesn't help. Perhaps choosing coherent IPs instead... (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737#section-3)

Comment: example is sometime i can to ping gateway-second, but sometimes not.. charon.log is same anytime, when i cant ping gateway-second, charon.log says CHILD_SA established but after it, not receive and send any traffic..

Comment: I'm not sure there are enough informations for somebody to give an immediate answer. You might have to double-check or even provide the whole network settings in: `ip -br link; ip -br addr; ip route; ip rule; iptables-save -c`. IPsec might need even more low level informations like `ip route show table 220; ip xfrm policy; ip xfrm state`. Keeping `ip xfrm monitor` (which appears to be very, perhaps too verbose) running might help, perhaps its output will display a clue when the problem appears, and then if you know there's a correlation you'd add it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by get one more public ip for server.
This is because remote site cant establish 2 tunnel on same peer.